# How to Select From IP in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to `select * from [IP Address]` in oracle. If using SQL Server, it's done like this:

```
  select * from [10.102.10.102].Crystal_KF_Prod.dbo.v_hrisappb7
```

How can I do this in Oracle SQL?
and How about From SQL to Oracle ?
Example
I Run this Query in Oracle (Toad) to View Table in SQL ?

```
select * from [10.102.10.102].Employee (This Table From SQL )
```

if From Oracle to SQL its done like This

```
Insert Into M_CLASSIFICATION_ORACLE 
SELECT * From OPENQUERY ([B1APPS], 'select * from V_Classification_Asset' ) AS derivedtbl_1
```

Comment: Do you really have IP-Addresses as table names?

Comment: Yes i have an IP Address + Table Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use database link for this.

from oracle to oracle it is simple as

```
create database link other_db 
    CONNECT TO remote_user IDENTIFIED BY password
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracledb.example.com)(PORT=1521))
                (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))
            )';
```

then

```
select * from tbl1@other_db
```

for oracle to other rdbms system, configuration is far more complex. you need to be much more specific

Comment: Hi Dervis , i already Edit my Topic, how about From SQL to Oracle ? can u help me again , thx

Comment: @AgusKalyana since sql to oracle is a new question, it is out of scope for this post. can you please open new question for that? And If this answer is helpful, please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer.